# Installed packages location when not using virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

Where are the packages installed if I don't use virtualenv? (ubuntu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the directories provided by the result of the following command:

```
python -m site
```

Comment: import sys; print sys.path

You need "site-packages" directory